# Rendering problem with PolygonMesh in JavaFX(yz)

Tags: java, javafx, rendering, mesh, fxyz3d

I am currently in the process of writing a program in which I read in various 3D meshes and continue working with them. The meshes usually contain triangles and quadrilaterals. I therefore wanted to use PolygonMesh from JavaFX(yz)3D so that the quadrilaterals do not have to be divided into two triangles and I can see directly in the GUI where triangles and quadrilaterals are.
Now I have tried out some simple examples and came across a problem that I could not find anywhere on the Internet.

Java does not render the PolygonMesh cleanly for me. At each edge of each created surface a tiny triangle appears, which does not seem to belong there. The phenomenon only occurs in DrawMode.LINE (below is a screenshot of the problem). The code is exactly from the answer under this question (without texture): [Problem with adding multiple triangle meshes to a scene in javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52554535/problem-with-adding-multiple-triangle-meshes-to-a-scene-in-javafx)

[the rendered wireframe from the site mentioned intext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRyRh.png)
[zoom in to one front edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9otr.png)

Am I missing something fundamental?

The phenomenon occurs even with a single rendered surface. Is this a known bug or what can I do?

Comment: From the answer you mentioned: `Under the hood, the Polygon mesh uses a triangle mesh, and internally converts the polygons you provide to triangles.`.  For every final edge, a very long and narrow triangle is used to create the visible effect of a line, so the internal triangleMesh is the collection of these triangles. But if you zoom close enough to the vertex, you can indeed see the real triangle. If you check the [code](https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz/blob/master/FXyz-Core/src/main/java/org/fxyz3d/shapes/polygon/PolygonMeshView.java#L331), that is the tiny offset used to define the triangle.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So am I right than that it is with javafx impossible to render a polygon with four or more edges in a 3D subscene in a clean way? This is a little disappointing, but it seems that it cannot be changed :(